# Is this expression for the energy of a three-body system correct assuming Newtonian mechanics?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy

In the (currently unanswered) Math SE question [Can there be an energetically unbounded three-body orbit where escape is impossible due to conservation of angular momentum?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3657498/284619) <s>I've</s> I'd written<sup>†</sup>:

> The total energy would be the sum of the kinetic and potential energies
>
> $$E = \sum_{i=1}^{3}\frac{1}{2}m_i v_i^2 - \sum_{i=1}^{3} \sum_{j=1}^{3} \frac{m_i m_j}{r_{ij}}; \ \ i \ne j$$

and

> $$\sum_{i=1}^3m_iv_i=0$$

was added later to exclude center-of-mass motion.

<sup>†</sup>Based on comments and my suspicion I've proactively amended the Math SE post.

Today I suddenly realized that I wrote the second term for potential energy off the top of my head, and I'm wondering if I've double counted or otherwise made a mistake.

Is this the correct expression for the total energy of three bodies assuming Newtonian mechanics? If not,  how should it be written?

Comment: You ave double counting the interactions. A factor $\frac12$ will settle the problem.

Comment: @GiorgioP ya that's what I was afraid of! Would replacing $i \ne j$ with $i > j$ work as well?

Comment: perhaps a duplicate of [Double counting potentials in -Body Problem?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/526282/83380)

Comment: That replacement is equivalent to the $1/2$ factor.

Comment: @GiorgioP yep, let's close it as duplicate, I was double-counting.